# Communication between ZigBee and Bluetooth

Tags: network-programming, bluetooth, communication, zigbee

[Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) and [ZigBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee)  devices are working or pairing within its own family devices based on parameters such as network layers, security algorithms, etc... I want to write an application to make a communication between ZigBee and Bluetooth device. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a gateway between the two networks.  Your application would need to interface with a ZigBee radio and a Bluetooth radio, join each network, and then proxy communications between devices on the networks.

What devices do you plan to bridge?  Your application will need to appear as device X on the ZigBee network, and device Y on the Bluetooth network and convert data received to the correct format to send out on the other network.

Answer (score 0):

If it were kept simple, something like this could work. A module that is a Zigbee presence, with a pairable bluetooth node. If a bluetooth-paired device comes near, the Zigbee announces itself as 'present'. When the bluuue tooth paired device is no longer around, the Zigbee device becomes "not present".